# button change start sound when click on it and stop if you move your finger

Tags: android

hi now i made app to run sound and change the picture if i pressed on it now if i pres on the picture the sound will run and the vibration but if i move my finger every thing will back As usual but the problem is that ; its run for one time then it will not run a Again and this is the code `public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Vibrator df;
//  protected MotionEvent event;

```
MediaPlayer mp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sh); 
        ImageButton m = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

        m.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN == arg1.getAction())
        {
            mp.start();
            df= (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

        }
        else
            if(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP == arg1.getAction())
            {

                mp.stop();
                df.cancel();
            }

            return false;
        }
    });


    }
        `
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [MediaPlayer reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html).

Calling stop() stops playback and causes a MediaPlayer in the Started, Paused, Prepared or PlaybackCompleted state to enter the Stopped state.
Once in the Stopped state, playback cannot be started until prepare() or prepareAsync() are called to set the MediaPlayer object to the Prepared state again.
Calling stop() has no effect on a MediaPlayer object that is already in the Stopped state.

so after calling stop(), you have to call prepare() before start().

Comment: please remember to adopt(upvote) my answer if it works for you. thanks